# How do I reset the setcounter for a custom lstlistingname in latex?

Tags: listings, counters

I am fairly new to the world of LaTeX and am currently working on a report. Throughout the report there are several tables, figures and commands. For the figures and tables I found the working code below which resets the counter and name for the commands in the supplements, yet I cannot find how to achieve this with a custom made `lstlistingname`.

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{command}


\newcommand{\beginsupplement}{%
        \setcounter{table}{0}
        \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}%
        \setcounter{figure}{0}
        \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}%
     }
```

I'd love to hear back about this matter, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: Apparently you're using the `listings` package, so I assume you have to reset the `lstlisting` counter, i.e. `\setcounter{lstlisting{0}`